Use chattr in Rstudio
I would like to test the newest chattr package to run an LLM model in Rstudio. Unfortunately, I'm not able to run it. I would like to run the llama model. We can download this model as described here:
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/kuvaus/LlamaGPTJ-chat
cd LlamaGPTJ-chat

And build it:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --parallel

This seems to work since I have the folder:

Now we need to setup the model like described here:
remotes::install_github("mlverse/chattr")
library(chattr)

chattr_use("llamagpt")
#> 
#> ── chattr
#> • Provider: LlamaGPT
#> • Path/URL: ~/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin/chat
#> • Model: ~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin
#> • Label: GPT4ALL 1.3 (LlamaGPT)

chattr_defaults()
#> 
#> ── chattr ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> ── Defaults for: Default ──
#> 
#> ── Prompt:
#> • Use the R language, the tidyverse, and tidymodels
#> 
#> ── Model
#> • Provider: LlamaGPT
#> • Path/URL: ~/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin/chat
#> • Model: ~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin
#> • Label: GPT4ALL 1.3 (LlamaGPT)
#> 
#> ── Model Arguments:
#> • threads: 4
#> • temp: 0.01
#> • n_predict: 1000
#> 
#> ── Context:
#> Max Data Files: 0
#> Max Data Frames: 0
#> ✖ Chat History
#> ✖ Document contents

chattr_defaults_save()

chattr_test()
#> Error in c("process_initialize(self, private, command, args, stdin, stdout, ", : ! Native call to `processx_exec` failed
#> Caused by error in `chain_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), pty, pty_options, …`:
#> ! cannot start processx process '/Users/quinten/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin/chat' (system error 2, No such file or directory) @unix/processx.c:613 (processx_exec)

Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0
Unfortunately, I get the error above. It looks like it can't find certain files but I'm not sure why this happens. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this issue?

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2020, with 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5.

Just a random guess, but I once had those random "could not find file" issues on my Mac because I only gave RStudio access to the Documents directory. Can you check if in your System Settings, Privacy and Security under Files and Folders or Full Disk Access RStudio has the necessary rights?

Can you run the model outside R? i.e. if you navigate to ~/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin and run ./chat -m "~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin" -t 4 , are you then talking to the model? Your error indicates that it is looking for ~/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin/chat, which expands to /Users/quinten/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin/chat, and that path doesn't exist. Is that right?

@Quinten Did you have any luck with chattr? Or discover any other clues to the problem?

Hi @SamR, Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to manage that.

@Ben, At the moment no success using the package.

Hi Quentin - try opening a terminal and typing cd ~/LlamaGPTJ-chat/build/bin. Can you enter the directory or does it produce an error saying it doesn't exist? If you can enter the dir, type ./chat -m "~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin" -t 4. Does that start the model or produce an error? If it starts the model the problem is what @FelixJassler said, that RStudio doesn't have the right permissions. If the model doesn't run, it's not installed properly. If that's the case, what error do you get?

@SamR, The directory works but entering the code returns this error: ./chat -m "~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin" -t 4 LlamaGPTJ-chat (v. 0.3.0) Your computer supports AVX512 .zsh: segmentation fault  ./chat -m "~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin" -t 4

OK great that's helpful. So this isn't (just) an R or RStudio problem. You can't run the R package because you can't run the model. You've got quite a new processor and the compiler has built this for an older processor. I think what you need to do is start again (delete the directory or clone the repo into a new directory), then at the point where you ran cmake --build . --parallel, replace it with cmake --build . --parallel -DAVX512=ON -LLAMA_AVX512=ON . If you do that and then try to run the model from that directory, you shouldn't see this error anymore.

Incidentally, you can see the build options in the makefile here. There are also VBMI and VNNI flags - whether you need to set them will depend on which processor you have. You could run sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu if you're not sure. You may be able to see which features your processor supports by running sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features. See here

@SamR, Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately running cmake --build . --parallel -DAVX512=ON -LLAMA_AVX512=ON results in Unknown argument -DAVX512=ON  in my terminal (I'm using Mac)

Hi Quentin actually what you need to do is this. Run cmake -DAVX512=ON  -DLLAMA_AVX512=ON . . This should turn on the relevant flags. You can check it worked by running cmake -LAH .. | grep AVX512. The output should include AVX512:BOOL=ON and LLAMA_AVX512:BOOL=ON. Then you can do cmake --build . --parallel. This is becoming quite complicated now. If it gets you anywhere let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

@SamR, It worked your latest comment, but unfortunately running ./chat -m "~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin" -t 4 still returns in an error: LlamaGPTJ-chat (v. 0.3.0) Your computer supports AVX512 .zsh: segmentation fault  ./chat -m "~/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin" -t 4

I suspect there's some combination of flags that will get this working. You might also need to turn AVX2 off, so when setting the flags do cmake -DAVX512=ON  -DLLAMA_AVX512=ON -DAVX2=OFF -DLLAMA_AVX2=OFF . . You may also need to turn on all AVX512 flags. What is the output of sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features?

@SamR, This is the output: machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX EST TM2 SSSE3 FMA CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 x2APIC MOVBE POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE SEGLIM64 TSCTMR AVX1.0 RDRAND F16C

That is weird - it says AVX1.0. I don't know much about Mac processors but that's different from the error message you were getting. What processor is it and how old is it?

@SamR, Added my intel processor to question above.

Looks like it should support AVX512 but I'm running out of ideas. Looking at their GitHub they seem to have built this on a Mac so I'd suggest posting a GitHub issue explaining what you've tried - they might know which compiler flags to set.
